# My NPM Vue library is not generating / exporting TS types

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

I'm creating a virtual scroller Vue 3 NPM library.

##### [Full source code](https://github.com/sigma-hub/sigma-scrollkit/)

#### Problem

It seems I'm not exporting or generating TS types properly. I specified the type paths in configs, package.json, etc, but it's still not generating any TS types.

When I import the library in another project as follows:

```js
import {VirtualScroller, VirtualScrollerRow} from 'sigma-scrollkit';
import type {VirtualEntry} from 'sigma-scrollkit';
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'sigma-scrollkit' or its corresponding type declarations
```

[image]

#### Library code

Package.json

```json
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "types/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "type": "module",
  "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "typings": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist/types",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
}
```

vite config

```json
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'sigma-scrollkit',
      fileName: 'sigma-scrollkit'
    },
    outDir: 'dist',
    emptyOutDir: true,
    minify: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        // Global vars for UMD build
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a index.d.ts at project root, [like this](https://github.com/sombriks/node-libgpiod/blob/main/index.d.ts).

Or point to types folder not from dist folder, [like this](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/package.json#L6).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I also needed to remove the const declarations from the types/index.d.ts: `declare module 'sigma-scrollkit'`. There's no errors now